# Does django have an installer for windows 7(32 bit) with python 3.3 installed?

Tags: django, windows-7, python-3.x

I searched for django for windows 7(32 bit) but couldn't find it [here](http://www.djangoproject.com/download/)

Answer (score 0):

You can install python from python official webpage:http://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.3.2/python-3.3.2.msi

You can download django installer from: Python Extension Package for windows website http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#django